# Plymouth scripting language manual

Tags: linux, boot, plymouth-script

I have plymouth script and I need to know more about its scripting language specifications. I have tried [Freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/Scripts/) specifications, but it is basic intro. There is no other Math object beside Image and Sprite. I need to know if there are more objects?

For example, because they said its code like JavaScript and C,

```
screen_width = Window.GetWidth();
screen_height = Window.GetHeight();
screen_x = Window.GetX();
screen_y = Window.GetY();
background_image = Image("BACKGROUND.PNG");
ratio = screen_height / screen_width;
background_ratio = background_image.GetHeight() / background_image.GetWidth();
factor = 0;

text_msg = Date.now()+"Said Bakr\nPlease Wait...";
```

However, `Date.now()` returns `#NULL`
I also need to know, is there any way to get bash commands output in variables of that script? such as `osName = $(uname)` the later returns error in the daemon.

Comment: Start browsing from here https://github.com/freedesktop/plymouth/blob/fbe2b79da56cf0a4b7ed5ca4754449ab4875b40f/src/plugins/splash/script/plugin.c#L270 , every function adds it's own set of functions to the language.

Comment: Well, till this point I get known that `String("aaa") returns `aaa` and `String("aaa").CharAt(1)` returns `1`. In the repo page you have regarded,  [time.h](https://github.com/freedesktop/plymouth/blob/fbe2b79da56cf0a4b7ed5ca4754449ab4875b40f/src/plugins/splash/script/plugin.c#L38) is included too. The idea, I could not able to implement those in the script, For example `Time(time_t)` returns NULL
@KamilCuk

Comment: I do not understand your comment at all. `time.h is included too` The __C source code__ includes the header `sys/time.h`. It's irrelevant to what happens to the plymouth script.The source code I posted __parses__ the script.That code on line 270 register functions are available in plymouth script. By inspecting the source code that registers script keywords you know which keywords are available. Ex [this line](https://github.com/freedesktop/plymouth/blob/fbe2b79da56cf0a4b7ed5ca4754449ab4875b40f/src/plugins/splash/script/script-lib-image.c#L274) registers `Image._New()` function.

Comment: Ie. generally, all [script_add_native_functions](https://github.com/freedesktop/plymouth/search?q=script_add_native_function) will give you all available script functions. There are also [script files](https://github.com/freedesktop/plymouth/blob/fbe2b79da56cf0a4b7ed5ca4754449ab4875b40f/src/plugins/splash/script/script-lib-image.script) for each lib I see, no idea what they do.